# JFoenix ListView is removing all items underneath selected

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a ListView where an item is added using a TextField's `onAction` event. A swipe across the item is required to remove it. 
Here is the code for adding an item:

```
private void addTask(String title) {
    Label label = new Label(newTask.getText());
    label.getStyleClass().add("task");
    label.setOnMousePressed((e -> {
        startX = e.getX();
    }));
    label.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
        endX = e.getX();
        if (endX - startX > 100)
            list.getItems().remove(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    });
    list.getItems().add(label);
}
```

Whenever an item gets removed, all the items below it get removed as well. I tried adding event listeners to the actual list, but the mouse clicks won't register on the items.

I am using [JFoenix](http://jfoenix.com) custom controls. Can that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what is your exact problem, but here is the code for deletion of the selected item on swipe action:

```
private double startX;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

    ObservableList<String> names = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise");
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(names);

    listView.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        startX = e.getX();
    });

    listView.setOnMouseReleased(e -> {
        if (Math.abs(e.getX() - startX) > 100) {
            listView.getItems().remove(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        }
    });
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 650);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

So, you don't need to add listeners for each items of ListView, the listView itself should handle mouse events.

Note, that the code above delete item on both left-right and right-left swipe.
If you want only one of them then for left-right swipe it would be:

```
 if (e.getX() - startX > 100) {
     listView.getItems().remove(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
 }
```

and for right-left:

```
 if (startX - e.getX()  > 100) {
     listView.getItems().remove(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
 }
```

Comment: For some reason, the clicks on the list items won't register on the list itself.  If I drag the cursor outside the items, it works.

Comment: All right, then you should share the code where you create your listview. Or even better write some small but complete application so that I could reproduce it on my side.

Comment: @theTechnoKid btw, just found out that there are numerous bugs in JFoenix, so you should try my code firstly and if it works as expected switch to JFoenix. If it doesn't work - there is most probably a bug and you may submit new issue on github.

Comment: I submitted an issue. I know how to do the slide, but the mouse events weren't registering on the list, so I tried to add listeners to the item itself, but that created its own problems.